# Automatically triggering standard spaceship controls to stop its motion

Tags: lua, love2d

I have been working on a 2D top-down space strategy/shooting game. Right now it is only in the prototyping stage (I have gotten basic movement) but now I am trying to write a function that will stop the ship based on it's velocity. This is being written in Lua, using the Love2D engine.

My code is as follows (note- object.dx is the x-velocity, object.dy is the y-velocity, object.acc is the acceleration, and object.r is the rotation in radians):

```
function stopMoving(object, dt)
    local targetr = math.atan2(object.dy, object.dx)
    if targetr == object.r + math.pi then
        local currentspeed = math.sqrt(object.dx*object.dx+object.dy*object.dy)
        if currentspeed ~= 0 then
            object.dx = object.dx + object.acc*dt*math.cos(object.r)
            object.dy = object.dy + object.acc*dt*math.sin(object.r)
        end
    else
        if (targetr - object.r) >= math.pi then
            object.r = object.r - object.turnspeed*dt
        else
            object.r = object.r + object.turnspeed*dt
        end
    end
end
```

It is implemented in the update function as:

```
if love.keyboard.isDown("backspace") then
    stopMoving(player, dt)
end
```

The problem is that when I am holding down backspace, it spins the player clockwise (though I am trying to have it go the direction that would be the most efficient at getting to the angle it would have to be) and then it never starts to accelerate the player in the direction opposite to it's velocity.

What should I change in this code to get that to work?

**EDIT :**

I'm not trying to just stop the player in place, I'm trying to get it to use it's normal commands to neutralize it's existing velocity.

I also changed math.atan to math.atan2, apparently it's better. I noticed no difference when running it, though.

Comment: Why not just `player.dx=0 player.dy=0`?

Comment: Because I'm not trying to tell it to just stop in place, I want it to use the ship's normal abilities in movement to cancel out it's motion. I'm going to edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: What are the "normal abilities" of the ship?

Comment: Turning left and right, accelerating and decelerating (accelerates in the opposite direction). Decelerating is half as powerful as accelerating.

Comment: Ok. Next, I don't understand your rotation comparisons: In the first (`targetr == object.r + math.pi`), why are you adding `pi`? In the second (`(targetr - object.r) >= 2*math.pi`), why are you comparing the value to a full circle (`2*pi`) instead of 0? Consider commenting your code. It's a good habit to get into, because it makes your intention clearer!

Comment: That was also a mistake, now corrected.

Comment: Still; why add pi? Also, does it work now?

Comment: It does not work now, even with a "close enough" test added. The adding of PI was so that it would be facing the opposite of it's velocity's angle.

Comment: Maybe this is too simple of an answer but, if you are able to slow down the player with normal movement controls (player hits up, down, left, or right) why not just use your 'down' button logic (or up if he is moving in reverse) every frame until he is within the close-enough-let's-just-zero-velocity range?

Comment: I only found it now, but [this answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560817/2d-trajectory-planning-of-a-spaceship-with-physics) should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drone targeting](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54350/drone-targeting)

Answer (score 2):

*I would strenuously urge you to give the player's ship retro-rockets to be used during braking.*

You really need to do that, because the alternative is for the computer to take over and automatically turn the ship to face away from its direction of travel whenever it decides that the player should stop.  That'll be intensely annoying to the player, having their ship start turning every time they take their fingers off the controls.

But with that said, the code to do so (say, for AI-controlled ships) would basically consist of a two-stage process;  first the ship would try to turn to face away from its direction of travel.  And once it's facing far enough away from its direction-of-travel, it thrusts to counteract its velocity, thrusting harder the more directly away from its direction of travel it might be.  Commented pseudocode (which assumes that angles are expressed in radians) follows:

```c
float pi = 3.141593;
float two_pi = pi * 2.0;
float half_pi = pi / 2.0;

void do_stop()
{
    // These are the values which we'll calculate.  We can then
    // use these values as if they were controller inputs.

    outval float steer, thrust;

    float angle_of_travel = atan2f(object.dy,object.dx);
    float angle_of_desired_braking = atan2f(-object.dy,-object.dx);
    float angle_of_facing = object.r;

    // Now calculate how many radians between the direction we're
    // currently facing and the direction we want to face for braking.

    float delta_angle = angle_of_desired_braking - angle_of_facing;

    // now normalise delta_angle back into [-pi .. pi], since the
    // above subtraction could have resulted in a value anywhere 
    // in [-two_pi .. two_pi].

    delta_angle = fmod(delta_angle, two_pi) - pi;

    // use a multiplication factor to control steering strength.

    const float c_steering_sensitivity = 0.5;
    steer = clamp( delta_angle * c_steering_sensitivity, -1.0, 1.0 );

    // Note that if you have rotational inertia, you'll need to 
    // further modify the steering value here, to try to slow down 
    // the rotation rate as you approach the desired orientation.
    // The sample code for this question doesn't imply the presence
    // of rotational inertia, so I'm leaving that out of this code.

    // Now if we're reasonably close to pointing the right 
    // direction, let's start thrusting.  c_thrust_threshold
    // states how close to correctly-aimed we need to be before
    // we'll start thrusting.

    const float c_thrust_threshold = half_pi;

    if ( fabs(delta_angle) <  c_thrust_threshold )
    {
        // modulate how hard we thrust based on how close we
        // are to pointing in the correct direction.

        thrust = 1.0 - fabs(delta_angle / c_thrust_threshold);
    }
    else
    {
        // don't thrust if we aren't pointing close enough 
        // to the desired direction for slowing down.

        thrust = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I could get it, the matter is that when you press the button, the speed of the object starts decreasing until it stops. You wantt to create a "break distance" (a distance between the X,Y place of pressing the button and the X,Y place of the place where the object stops) to create some kind of realistic breaking.

Don't really get the stuff doing with degrees, though.

So here's my suggestion for solving this problem: simply create a function (let's call it `stopMoving` as you did too) that runs an iteration that closes `dx` and `dy` to 0, and call it `love.update`.

Something like `for i = object.dx, 0, -1 do` in case of `dx>0` and same code **without** `-1` in case of `dx<0`. And same for `dy`.

If you want to be precise, try to iterate with the greatest common divisor of x and y. `-1/+1` is also a common divisor for any whole x and y, but that may result a very small speed decreasing.

All above are just ideas, but may be worth a try. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

The problem you're running into is the fact that when your player has stopped, there's no angle to work with so the game can't know which way to move backwards.

You either need to add one more variable that keeps track of the angle your `dx`/`dy` variables are on or two more variables to store `dx`/`dy`, leaving them alone when your real `dx`/`dy` variables don't change (and they can be safely left when their *magnitude* alone changes), but updating them when their *direction* changes.
(I think it would suffice to keep your "backup" `dx`/`dy` variables updated everywhere else save for your `stopMoving()` function)

Comment: This isn't the issue. If the player had stopped, it would have been caught by the "if currentspeed ~= 0". That means it wouldn't continue after the player has stopped. My issue is that it never even stops turning, and that no matter what the angle is, it always goes in the same direction.

Comment: Hmm. Once I have a better handle on your problem, I'll replace my answer with something better suited. Are you sure you're calculating the angle `object.r` correctly?

Comment: Object.r is fine, sonce I've been able to move the player around using normal controls just fine. It's not being calculated, it's being called.

Comment: Why are you performing this exacting comparison? `targetr == object.r + 2*math.pi' If floating-point values are compared, more often than not they won't be equal.

Comment: So you'd suggest something to test if they are within something like 1% of each other?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The desired result is that the ship slows down, but since it's spinning instead, the first part of your `if` block isn't getting executed. Therefore, the condition isn't being met.